# How to create and mount a RAM disk at computer startup?

Tags: mount, tmpfs, ramdisk

This is how I create RAM disk manually on Linux Debian Jessie:

```
mount -o size=1G -t tmpfs none /mnt/tmpfs
```

My question is, how do I make this automatic at each computer startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a script for that: there's a system facility to mount a filesystem at boot time. Add it to the file [`/etc/fstab`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab). Open this file in your favorite text editor and add a line like this:

```
none /mnt/tmpfs tmpfs size=1G
```

Make sure not to accidentally modify other lines.

Note that there's already a tmpfs filesystem¹ mounted at `/run`. Debian doesn't make `/tmp` tmpfs by default, but you can make it so by editing `/etc/default/tmpfs` and changing the `RAMTMP` line to

```
RAMTMP=yes
```

¹  <sub>This isn't a RAM disk: it doesn't reserve memory, only the space used for files takes up memory, and its pages can be swapped out just like application data.</sub>

Comment: I suspect that this may be wrong, at least for my distro (Xbian) since "df -h" output shows Filesystem to be none and not tmpfs. Am i wrong? But what created tmpfs type Filesystem was fstab "tmpfs /mnt/tmpfs tmpfs size=1G".

To make it writeable by regular first user, i think one can use:
tmpfs /mnt/tmpfs tmpfs size=100M,mode=0755,uid=1000 0 0
(note that you need to make directory: mkdir /mnt/tmpfs)

Comment: @16851556 What part do you think is wrong? Re-reading, I can't see a mistake. This answer was written a long time ago, before systemd, but the part about `/etc/default/tmpfs` seems to still be true on bullseye. Note that the “Filesystem” column in the output of `df` is normally the path to the device, and it isn't meaningful for tmpfs. If you want to check whether a directory is on tmpfs, you need to check the **filesystem type**, which you can display with `df -T`.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me to setup immediate and on-boot mounted tmpfs partition. Before executing, set inside a proper uid (returned by command "id") and replace 100M (megabytes) by your size. Execute inside a root terminal:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/tmpfs
&& echo "tmpfs /mnt/tmpfs tmpfs size=100M,mode=0755,uid=1000 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
&& mount -a && df -h
```

Then login as normal user and verify that the user is able to create content in /mnt/tmpfs/ meaning that uid= was set correctly.